# Code Igniter Twitter GET Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-oauth

Working on a legacy CI project to include the option for users to authorise a twitter app to allow the site to post DMs to the users (not my idea)

I plugged in the twtest GIT project from [epoberezkin](https://github.com/epoberezkin/twitter-codeigniter) in a fresh install of CI yesterday and everything worked well. However when I plug it into the legacy CI framework it breaks and does not allow the user to be connected. I think I have narrowed it down to this function:

public function twprocess_callback() {
    $ci = & get_instance();

```
$data = $ci->input->get();
$returned_request_token = $ci->input->get('oauth_token');
```

.....

The variable $returned_request_token is empty always but in my standalone version it takes the value from the GET and works as expected.

I ran a `print_r($)_SERVER)` and the data is there but the CI implementation to get the particular part of the `GET` does not work. I can explode and get it manually but I was hoping for a more CI-centric explanation.

Is there anything in CI that turns off the GET methods?

Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be config problem.  What is the value of

```
$config['allow_get_array']
```

in your config.php?

Comment: Thanks for that. Must be an old CI install because it wasnt there at all in the legacy site but was in my fresh install. Will add it and see if it works.